# How to get public rsa key from p,q,d

Tags: key, rsa

I have only this and i dont know how to calculate the private key.

```
const char* p("11255972776556904264355589361581299560395728872239621233068906405812608921813191755808405540044481084831045609458696035640942585319975255128754117171584651");
const char* q("7289733069892282545374975427138985921459336460098199998353496532104650473441707994051054607475682163000818993472760435603314465037312588601022012551228891");
const char* d("70043748630820478511883011265666731045146072028066310178672809101054479215166107831769673593025767853213311605740951029471462199049707526773053884221428550051565790192707552723439555048621215503776643878462109243202624983405481154406252935541613799894609964410988575108271598180781588706290307870314111895973");
```

Comment: Could you give us a little bit more info?

Comment: You don't know how? Then [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation).

Answer (score 2):

> I have only this and i dont know how to calculate the private key.

You already know the private key: when talking about `p`, `q` and `d` with RSA, `p`, `q` are the prime numbers and `d` is the private key.

So, the only thing you do not know is the public key. It is `(p*q, e)`, for which `e` is the public exponent. With many RSA libraries, `e` is 3 or 65537. It is easy to see that you have not chosen one of these values for `e`: if you had chosen one of these two values, then either `(3*d-1) / ((p-1)(q-1))` or `(65537*d-1) / ((p-1)(q-1))` would have been an integer. I've computed these two formulas with this [online big number calculator](https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm) and they do not give integers. So, you have not chosen one of the common values for `e`.

Therefore, you need to compute `e` by yourself, using the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) with `(p-1)(q-1)` and `d` as input. The value of the Bézout coefficient for `d` will be `e`. Here is an example implementation of this algorithm with C, C# and Python, but not for big numbers: [implementating the extended euclidean algorithm](http://www.techiedelight.com/extended-euclidean-algorithm-implementation/).